# Excel vba Underscore .Delete_

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to find the right answer that fits to my code.

I'm trying to delete the first row on `Sheet1`
I'm sure my code below would work

But throws me a Run time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Delete_
```

The following is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub C2P()
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C,F:F").Replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Delete_
End Sub
```

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: nope it's not! Maybe that was causing issue @TnTinMn

Comment: @TnTinMn Ha! It does work! Please post a question, i'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @YowE3K OP is new to vba, and does not understand that the `_` indicates that the next line is part of the first.

Comment: @YowE3K My goal is delete the first row on Sheet1. 
Since I used 'Replace_' I thought I also had to use 'Delete_'.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for the comment! Learning every day!

Comment: The line continuation token is [WS]+[UNDERSCORE]; in `Delete_` the underscore is considered part of the `Delete` method name (and `Delete_` doesn't exist as a member of `Range`, hence error 438); also a line continuation would be illegal there anyway. Avoid line continuations whenever possible.

Comment: You actually used `...Replace _` (with a space to separate the underscore from the preceding token).  Without the space, `Replace_` would have given compilation errors on the `What...` line (as it isn't valid syntax).  If you had been consistent and used `...Delete _` (with a space) you would have also gotten syntax errors and it would have highlighted the line starting at the `W` on the `Delete` line and ending at the `B` of that line.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you so much! I couldn't be more grateful!

Comment: @YowE3K Very wise answer. Underscore was the key. Thank you so so much as always!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra character in the Delete method name.
`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Delete_`
Remove the underscore.

Learn to use the "F1" key to bring up the built in help system.  It is there for a reason.